# How to change video tag's forwarding time

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have video tag on my website and when i click right arrow, it forwards with about 1 minute and i want to reduce this time to 10 seconds.

`<video src="SOURCE" controls="true" id="video" style="height: 477px; width: 980px"></video>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach an eventlistener directly to the video instead of the site.

```js
  
  var video = document.getElementById("video");
  var timer = 10;
  video.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
   event.preventDefault();
   switch (event.keyCode) {
         case 37:  
              var currentTime = video.currentTime;
              video.currentTime = currentTime - timer;
            break;
         
         case 39:
               var currentTime = video.currentTime;
              video.currentTime = currentTime + timer;
            break;
            }
});
```

```html
 <video controls="true" id="video" style="height: 477px; width: 480px">
   <source src="https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can attach an event handler on this arrow key and then change the currentTime property. But prevent the default behaviour before.

```js
const $video = document.querySelector('video');
const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.keyCode === 39) {
    const seconds = $video.currentTime;
    $video.currentTime = seconds + 10;
  }
}

$video.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
```

```html
<video width="320" height="200">
  <source src="your/file.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<p>Hello</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

- https://www.codespeedy.com/forward-and-backward-html5-video-player-javascript/

You can use event.preventDefault() to prevent default forwarding and set manual forward by adding currentTime + 10 seconds.